# Katalon API tests, can not use APIs whcih returns cookies

Tags: testing, cookies, katalon-studio, web-api-testing, httpcookie

For the first time I'm trying API testing so pardon me if I'm not clear with the problem. I'm using Katalon to test some API's. It runs quite well with REST API's but when I send request to an API which should return cookie and a redirect status code 302 its sending response like this,

```
We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
```

The request is to windows graph API which authenticates the user using access token and then redirects to user to the application.

Comment: Ok after digging along with the code I found that the problem was because of redirect. The API of my application was redirecting to Microsoft login page which was causing the problem.